# Bootstrap: How to enable scroll bars?

Tags: scroll, scrollbar, twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter Bootstrap in one of my projects, but I have the problem that my content goes out of the browser view. Normally you see the scrollbar on the right side of the screen, but not in my case. I searched in bootstrap css file after `overflow: hidden;` or something like that and deleted it, but that didn't solve the problem.

Does someone know how to enable scrollbar in bootstrap css?  (without bootstrap css the bars are showed)

edit:

I have find out that the problem the `navbar-fixed` in the black navbar which you can add. Without `postition: fixed` it works fine.

Comment: Post some code so we can take a look, we can't diagnose your problem blindly.

Comment: I believe the issue is somewhere in your CSS file, some code or link to your project would be useful, have you tried to check your container in Firebug?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997192/twitter-bootstrap-fixed-layout-with-scrollable-sidebar

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem is solved. I can't close this?

Comment: Yes, you close it by posting an answer to your own question and then marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found removing the "position: fixed" for the navbar resolved this problem for me:**

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
    /*position: fixed;*/
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

This guy also has some more useful info: http://davidlains.com/strange-twitter-bootstrap-scrolling-issue

Comment: As a note to everyone, in my case, I found out I had `overflow: hidden` on my body style.  Took forever to find that.

Answer (score 16):

Make sure all the `<div>` from the navbar are closed. If not, the fixed property is inherited by the descending tags and the scroll bars disappears.

Answer (score 3):

Override it with your last stylesheet.
( Probably your own theme stylesheet. )

```
html, body {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Was also forced to do this overflow:visible!important on the body class. Removing position:fixed didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
            body, html {
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .navbar-inner {
                height: 40px;
            }

            .scrollable {
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .max-height {
                height: 100%;
            }

            .no-overflow {
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .pad40-top {
                padding-top: 40px;
            }
    </style>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing `</div>` in your HTML code. For every `<div class="foobar">` you must have a closing `</div>`. This (scrolling issue) can happen when using twitter bootstrap and not closing your divs.