# Modernizr + Bootstrap 2/3 => browser's scrollbar disappears

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, browser, modernizr

I use Twitter Bootstrap 3.0-RC1 combining with Modernizr 2.6.2. 
(the issue is also reproducible with Bootstrap 2.X.X)

I struggled to find why my browser didn't show any scrollbar, traditionally on the right side. (of course I tried to minimize my browser's window in order to see it)

I first found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10320608/bootstrap-how-to-enable-scroll-bars) post, potentially linked with my issue, since I also use the `navbar` component of bootstrap.

I find that when I remove the second line of this snippet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="javascripts/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the whole works meaning the scrollbar appears.

Is it a normal behavior from modernizr to remove scrollbar regarding some context?